# How to pass add-module to spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using a maven dependency which require me to pass `add-module` during compilation and runtime as mentioned [here](https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization#mvn).

Can someone let me know how can I pass `--add-module` option to a spring boot application during compilation and runtime? It will be good if I can control both compilation and runtime behaviour from the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For compilation you can use the `maven-copmiler-plugin` in your build of your `pom.xml`.

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <parameters>true</parameters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>14</source>
                    <target>14</target>
                    <compilerReuseStrategy>reuseSame</compilerReuseStrategy>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                        <arg>--add-modules=jdk.incubator.foreign</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

As you see I have included also the `--enable-preview`. In JDK14 as reported in [JEPS 370](https://openjdk.org/jeps/370) it is not needed since this is not a preview feature. But keep an eye on it since it might be needed in other jdk versions since in some versions this belongs in preview features.

As for runntime a `spring-boot` application is normally just a `.jar` executable file which you start with the normal `java -jar myApp.jar` command.

According to [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624), the format of the command line is

> To execute a JAR file:
>
> java [options] -jar jarfile [args...]

So the command you want would be

```
java --add-modules jdk.incubator.foreign -jar myApp.jar
```